# How to setup \cite

Tags: biblatex

I use footnotes with `\footcite{quante2012person}` and have the source defined in my `.bib`-file like this:

```
@book{quante2012person,
  title={Person},
  author={Quante, Michael},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Walter de Gruyter}
}
```

Now I also want to use \cite{quante2012person} so that there is no footcite. It works, but I just want to have the last name, the year and the page number and not the whole data which is set in the `@book`-tag. How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**
I get this as result:
[image]

I am not sure which style I am using, but this is in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{biblio}
\addbibresource{references/biblio.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
     \usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
    \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}
```

Comment: Usually, you get just the name and date for an authooryear style. Which style are you using? Please show us a minimal working example.

Comment: @Johannes_B Please see my edit.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to give you a helpful link: [Creating a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: Right now, we are just as able to help as a car mechanic is by looking at a photo of a car. We need to see the code to reproduce :-)

Comment: Well, the problem (as it were) clearly comes from your `\renewbibmacro*`. Is that your own definition or did you copy it from somewhere else?

Comment: Can you provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for your problem, please? Can you also explain in more detail what output you want? Do you want the full info on `\footcite` and short author-year like citations on `\cite`?

Comment: Any news here? Or any answers to my questions above?

Comment: @jon No, I copied it somewhere.

Comment: @moewe Exactly! I trie to provide a full MWE.

Comment: What about subsequent `\footcite` citations should they still be shortened as in the `vebose` style? Should they be shortened if the work has been `\cite`d before or only if it has been `\footcite`d before?

Comment: Another thing came to my mind: What if there are several works by the same author from the same year? Do you want the disambiguation you get with `authoryear` styles (i.e. 1986a, 1986b, etc.)? Do you want your bibliography to feature the year more prominently? (Cf. `bibstyle=authoryear`) Do you want the subsequent short citations in `\footcite` to be author-year as well, or are you OK with author-title there?

Comment: @moewe The should still be shortened as in the vebose style. It should only be shortened if it has been footcited before. It will not happen that I use several works by the same author from the same year. But a nice idea! In the footcite author-title is ok.

Comment: But is it not going to be very confusing that you have essentially two short forms to refer to a work?

Comment: @moeve You are right...I just realized that I have two same short forms. How can I add this a/b/c style?

Comment: Please comment below my answer what you would like to have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can steal the code needed for author-year citations from `authoryear.cbx`

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:authoryear}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
```

Then we ask for author-year style in `\cite` and `\parencite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:authoryear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:authoryear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

You should load `biblatex` with the option `labeldate` and add

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdateextralabel}
```

to get the year disambiguation in the bibliography.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber, labeldate]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
      \usedriver
        {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
        {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
    \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:authoryear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:authoryear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:authoryear}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdateextralabel}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{sigfridsson} \cite{worman} ipsum\footcite{geer}

Lorem\footcite{sigfridsson} \cite{worman} ipsum\footcite{geer}

Lorem\footcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} ipsum\footcite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} dolor \cite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\cite{cicero} lorem\footcite{cicero}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: example output]